# Angular6 validate modal by pressing enter

Tags: angular

I have a modal that I would like to validate by pressing enter I call it like this:

```
<app-group-edit #newGroup id='add-group' class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"
  (onGroupUpdate)='onGroupCreate(newGroup.editedGroup)'></app-group-edit>
```

and this is the modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <input id="{{editedGroup.id}}" placeholder="Nom du groupe" [(ngModel)]="editedGroup.name" 
    autofocus>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-3" data-dismiss="modal" (click)='onNoClick($event)'>Valider</button>
</div>
```

I tried putting button type as "submit" as some suggested in other posts without luck.

I also tried adding (keyup.enter)='onNoClick($event)' to the input field which triggers the event fine but then how do I close the modal from inside my function? For this I found some solutions with JQuery but nothing with angular.

I am probably missing something here, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `*ngIf` to set the state (open/closed) relative to the modal. And change the value of the variable binded to that ngIf in your `onNoClick` function

Comment: you want to close `app-group-edit` from parent with child `keyup.enter` event, am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options : when your modal is being opened, you can use an event listener to listen to the document.

```
@HostListener('window:keypress.enter', [$event]) {
  // Your code to close the modal
}
```

And to simulate a click on the closing button, you can use a ViewChild/template variable :

```html
<button #closeButton type="button" class="btn btn-3" data-dismiss="modal" (click)='onNoClick($event)'>Valider</button>
```

```js
@ViewChild('closeButton') closeButton: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
@HostListener('window:keypress.enter', [$event]) {
  this.closeButton.nativeElement.click();
}
```

You can also bind your input to mock the click on the button :

```
<input id="..." placeholder="..." [(ngModel)]="..." (keyup.enter)="closeButton.click()">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the second option, it works exactly as intended.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create one template driven form like this in your HTML file.

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onNoClick($event)" #f="ngForm" novalidate  ><div class="modal-body">
  <input id="{{editedGroup.id}}" placeholder="Nom du groupe" [(ngModel)]="editedGroup.name" 
    autofocus> 
  <div class="modal-footer">
     <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-3" data-dismiss="modal"  >Valider</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But it will be helpful to apply further validations

Comment: I agree, but that is too much code for what the OP asked

Comment: OP might not aware about further user use of the template driven form.
so it was just additional info from my part :-)

Comment: This returns : Unexpected closing tag "form". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("